# JSON.parse fails on ObjectId

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I am trying to convert a string for use in mongodb but fails.

```
    let pipeline = JSON.parse('[{"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("5b5637acbd3e9c2068ef80c3")}]');
    // results in  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 20"s

    let pipeline = JSON.parse('[{"$match": {"_id": "5b5637acbd3e9c2068ef80c3"}]');
    let response = await db.collect('<collection_name>').aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
    // returns []  parse works but mongodb doesn't return any rows!

    // This works but its not the solution I am looking for.
    let pipeline = [{"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("5b5637acbd3e9c2068ef80c3")}];
    let response = await db.collect('<collection_name>').aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
```

I tried using the BSON type but had no luck.

My current work around is to remove the ObjectId() from the string and use a Reviver function with JSON.parse

```
    const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

    let convertObjectId = function (key,value){
        if (typeof value === 'string' && value.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)){
            return ObjectId(value);
        } else {
            return value;
        };
    }

    let pipeline = JSON.parse('[{"$match": {"_id": "5b5637acbd3e9c2068ef80c3"}]',convertObjectId);
    let response = await db.collect('<collection_name>').aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
    // returns one record.
```

Comment: `[{"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("5b5637acbd3e9c2068ef80c3")}]` is not a valid json. Check it from [here](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: May I know why do you want to parse it.

Comment: The purpose of this exercise is so I can pass a mongodb pipeline thru API / req.body. I am writing a browser based tool for working with mongodb aggregations (because I am tired of struggling with Studio 3T)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `[{"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("5b5637acbd3e9c2068ef80c3")}]` is not valid JSON.

The value of a property in JSON can only be an object (ex.: `{}`), an array (ex.: `[]`), a string (ex.: `"abc"`), a number (ex.: `1`), a boolean (ex.: `true`), or `null`. See an example of these values here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Example.

What you could do is add `ObjectId()` manually after parsing the JSON. This would mean that the value of `_id` would be a string first, which is valid JSON.

Then, you can loop through your parsed JSON to add `ObjectId` (see reference here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html):

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const pipeline = JSON.parse('[{"$match": {"_id": "5b5637acbd3e9c2068ef80c3"}]');
const pipelineWithObjectId = pipeline.map(query => ({
    $match: {
        ...query.$match,
        _id: ObjectId(query.$match._id)
    }
});
const response = await db.collect('<collection_name>').aggregate(pipelineWithObjectId).toArray();
```

This should work with the example you provided but there are multiple caveats:

- Parsing a query like that could be a vulnerability if the string contains user input that has not been sanitized: https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html.
- This particular code snippet would only work for queries with `$match`, which means that this code is not very scalable.
- This code is not elegant.

All these reasons, for what they are worth, make me think that you would be better off using an object rather than a string for your queries.

Comment: That's what my Reviver function does.  The purpose of this exercise is so I can pass a mongodb pipeline thru API / req.body.  I am writing a browser based tool for working with mongodb aggregations (because I am tired of  struggling with Studio 3T)

Comment: Ah! Yes, I empathize. I have mixed feelings about Studio 3T. Does the solution of injecting `ObjectId` like I demonstrated in the code snippet not work for you?